# Как изменять размер шрифта в Entry tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, entry

Именно если Entry уже создан, а размер шрифта нужно изменить. Скажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```
from tkinter import *


def change_font():
    ent['font']=10
window = Tk()
window.title("Размещение документации на сервере")
window.geometry('1200x400')
ent = Entry(window, text='что-то там')
ent.pack()
but = Button(command=change_font)
but.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Так же можно обращаться к любым свойствам виджетов и изменять их